# Dice rolling / Smallest value probability

Tags: probability, dice

> If $X$ is the smallest number when rolling a die $n$ times. Then how can we obtain the PDF/CDF? I thought as for $1\leq{i}\leq6$ how to find $P(X=i)$.

Example: Throws$=(3,2,4,4,5)\implies X=2$. If we want to generalize this into a PDF/CDF, I was trying to use the formula $X=\min{(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)}$.

I don't know how to apply the whole formula and get to the general PDF/CDF.
 Any tips would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to find $P(X\ge i)$, it's not too difficult : the event $X\ge i$ is realized when all the throws gave a result greater than $i$, so it's $\left(\frac{7-i}{6}\right)^n$.

After that, 
$$P(X=i)=P(X\ge i)-P(X\ge i+1)=\left(\frac{7-i}{6}\right)^n-\left(\frac{7-(i+1)}{6}\right)^n$$
for $1\le i\le 5$, and 
$$P(X=6)=P(X\ge6)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since different rolls are independent and have the same distribution, you have that \begin{align}P(X> x)&=P(\min{\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}}> x)]=P(X_1> x, X_2> x,\dots,X_n>x)=^{\text{independce}}\\[0.2cm]&=P(X_1>x)P(X_2>x)\dots P(X_n>x)=^{\text{identically distributed}}\\[0.2cm]&=P(X_1>x)^n=(1-P(X_1\le x))^n\end{align} Hence, the CDF $F_X$ of $X$ is given by $$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=1-P(X>x)=1-(1-P(X_1\le x))^n=1-(1-F_1(x))^n$$ where $F_1$ denotes the CDF of $X_1$. So, all reduces in finding the CDF of one roll.

Comment: Thank you! But i see that you used the property 1-(1-F(x))^n. Now why is it that the pdf formula is stated as nf(x)(1-F(x))^n-1? I dont see that back in the logic of applying those two theorems.

Comment: The pdf is just the derivative of the cdf in case it exists. So, if you differentiate $F_X(x)$ you will get the $f_X(x)$ that you say. But here you have no pdf since you have a discrete distribution. However you know the pdf of one roll, it is uniform on $\{1,\dots, 6\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a verification of the results in the very nice Answer of @NicholasFRANCOIS,
for the case $n = 8$, based on simulating the 8-roll experiment a million times
and finding the minimum face number $Y$ for each experiment.

```
m = 10^6;  n = 8;  die=1:6
x = sample(die, m*n, rep=T)
DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)      # m x n matrix; each row has results of one n-roll expt
y = apply(DTA, 1, min)
table(y)/m
#     y
#        1        2        3        4        5        6  # simulated dist'n
# 0.767262 0.193576 0.035219 0.003779 0.000163 0.000001 

hist(y, prob=T, br=(0:6)+.5, col="wheat")
   pdf=numeric(6)
   i = 1:5;  pdf[1:5] = ((7-i)/6)^n - ((7-i-1)/6)^n
   pdf[6] = (1/6)^n
points(1:6, pdf, col="blue", pch=19)

round(pdf, 6)
# 0.767432 0.193550 0.035112 0.003754 0.000152 0.000001  # exact dist'n
```

The histogram shows simulated results, and the blue dots atop histogram
bars show exact results. The resolution of the graph shows only about 
two decimal places, simulated results are accurate to about three places.

[image]

*Note:* I started by simulating the case $n = 10,$ but then minimums are
almost entirely 1's and 2's.